# Save Text Output without overwriting?

Tags: php

My PHP script will overwrite the existing output on my localhost. This is my code:

```
$txt = "data.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w'); 
if (isset($_POST['idnumber']) && isset($_POST['idnumber'])) {
    $txt = $_POST['idnumber']; 
    file_put_contents('data.txt',$txt."\n",FILE_APPEND);
}
fwrite($fh,$txt);
fclose($fh);
}
```

How can I keep it from overwriting?

Comment: yes all the time is an new output i need all in one output without overwriting

Comment: Please don't remove all the content of your post after you find an answer. This prevents others from learning from your mistake. I've rolled back the edit for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are overwriting your file with the fwrite() function.

There is no need for using fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() functions if you are using file_put_contents() function.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
$fh = fopen($txt, 'w');
```

To this:

```
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a');
```

Which will append the data vs. writing the data (adding vs. overwriting).

Answer (score 1):

You need a different mode than `w` in your call to `fopen`.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for all your options.

Also, you should always check the return from `fopen` to see if it succeeded.

Comment: nice list thanks for the tip:)